# Why does air not flow backwards in Jet Engines in the combustion chamber?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, aerodynamics, combustion

In jet engines air is taken in, compressed and then fuel is injected and then ignited forcing the turbine to spin powering the compressor. What I am curious about is why the combusted air isn't forced out the front of the turbine? Basically why does air only go out the back?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do turbine engines work?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/114280/)

Answer (score 1):

In the front of the jet engine is a huge fan which is continuously cramming air into the combustor cans at high pressure and speed. Because of that fan, the hot combustion gases are prevented from getting blown upstream.

Being hot, they want to expand, and the only expansion path available to them is out the tailpipe. As they expand, they accelerate, and leave the cans going downstream lots faster than they entered the cans.

That process happens very quickly, at essentially constant pressure.

Then they pass through the turbine stage, which picks up most of their kinetic energy and uses that to keep the fan spinning. the rest of the kinetic energy is responsible for generating thrust.

Comment: I have also always had a problem with the fact that jet engines work. The answer by niels nielsen only restates the principle that I have known for many years but doesn't stop it from being somewhat counter-intuitive. A pulse jet has valves and so seems easy to accept. Incidentally it's interesting that, just like an internal combustion engine, a turbojet has induction, compression, ignition and exhaust, but they are in a continuous process.

Comment: @RobTristram, well I tried. But key to the brayton cycle is the idea that the combustion heat is added at constant pressure. all else flows from that fact.

Comment: I'm sure you're right.